# If we know the factors of an integer, what is the easiest way to know the factors of the next integer?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

If I want to get the factors of an integer $N+1$, does it help if I already know the unique factorization of $N$? If so, how?

Comment: Well, when looking for factors of $N+1$, you can exclude all the factors of $N$ from your search.

Comment: The $abc$-conjecture can give you done heuristics, specifically that the product of distinct primes in $N(N+1)$ is probably not much larger than $N$.

Comment: Other than you know the factors will be completely different (i.e. will have entirely different primes) it doesn't help you in the least.

Comment: If your idea worked, one could easily factor Fermat numbers $2^{2^n}+1.$

Comment: Knowing the prime factorization of $N=(N+1)-1$ does help proving that found factors of $N+1$ are prime via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test

Comment: Well, one **can** easily (if not completely) factor the numbers of the form $2^n+1$ which are _not_ Fermat numbers, and also those of the form $2^n-1$ which are not Mersenne numbers. So it does help, but not much, and that only in certain rare cases.

Comment: If $N$ is odd, then you already know that $N + 1$ has $2$ for a least prime factor. Beyond that, I don't know...

Comment: To know the factorization of $N$ (without any additional information) does not help to find any odd prime factor of $N+1$. We can only conclude that $2$ is a prime factor of $N+1$ , if it is not a prime factor of $N$.